# "Newline in constant" error in ASPX <script runat="server"> block

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have the following code and and have been working at it for hours. I keep getting the "Newline in constant" error and cannot figure out what to do with the following code to fix the issue. The issue happens on the line with the script string where I am adding the ajax.googleapis.com script.

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="True" Inherits="XXX.XXX.XXXX" %>
<script runat="server">
    private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var script = String.Empty; 
        if(!(Request.Browser.Type.ToUpper().Contains("IE") || Request.Browser.Type.ToUpper().Contains("INTERNETEXPLORER")))
        {
            script = "<script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js'></script>";
        }
        ScriptLiteral.Text = script; 
    }
</script>
```

Here is the error message I'm getting:

> ## Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> ### *Compilation Error*
>
> **Description:** An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> **Compiler Error Message:** CS1010: Newline in constant
>
> **Source Error:**
>
> ```
> Line 18:  if(!(Request.Browser.Type.ToUpper().Contains("IE") || Request.Browser.Type.ToUpper().Contains("INTERNETEXPLORER")))
> Line 19:  {
> Line 20:      script = "<script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js'></script>";
> Line 21:  }
> Line 22:  ScriptLiteral.Text = script;
> ```
>
> **Source File:** c:\inetpub\selfcarehome.com\default.Master    **Line:** 20

Comment: whats the error your getting

Comment: Also, why are you writing javascript in the aspx file in .net and pushing it out instead of simply using javascript

Comment: Can you please post the full error as it is on screen?

Comment: I can see you're missing a closing brace on the `if` block, but that makes no sense with the error message.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, the missing closing brace was actually a formatting error when pasted into Stack Overflow.

Comment: Added Error Message to this question. Not sure why this question was voted down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `</script>` tag within the string literal on line 20. When ASP.NET parses your markup, it sees the `<script runat="server">` tag and then looks for the corresponding`</script>` tag. However, the parser doesn't understand C# syntax, nor does it handle nested `<script>` tags. Thus, ASP.NET thinks your server-side script block ends in the middle of line 20, and so it sends the following code to the C# compiler:

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var script = String.Empty; 
    if(!(Request.Browser.Type.ToUpper().Contains("IE") || Request.Browser.Type.ToUpper().Contains("INTERNETEXPLORER")))
    {
        script = "<script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js'>
```

It should now be obvious why the C# compiler thinks there's a newline within the string.

To avoid this problem, split the `</script>` tag into pieces:

```
script = "<script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js'><" + "/script>";
```

Comment: Extremely helpful. Thanks